Spheres centered at an adherent point
Let $Y\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ and $z\in\overline{Y}$ . For every $t>0$ consider the set $$Y(t)=\{y\in Y \,;\ |z-y|=t\}$$ where $|\cdot|$ is the euclidean distance.
Question: under which conditions $Y(t)$ is non empty for all sufficiently small $t$ ?
I think that we need to ask of Y to be connected or at least having finitely many connected components
Am I right? and how to show this.

I believe that "finitely many connected components", as you suggest, is not correct. Take $Y=\mathbb{Q}^+\cup \mathbb{I}^-\subset \mathbb{R}$. You have $z=0\in \overline{Y}$, and certainly points in $Y$ at any given distance $t$ from $z$; but $Y$ is totally disconnected (even in a nbh of $z$).

@WishYouTheBest What is meant by $\mathbb{I}$?

@K.Jiang irrational numbers

@WishYouTheBest Ah, I see. Nice example!

@WishYouTheBest nice example. But what about when Y has finitely many connected component? can we affirm that $Y(t)$ is non empty for all sufficiently small $t$??

If $Y$ is a singleton, then $Y(t)$ is always empty. But if $Y$ is not a singleton and is connected, then yes, the result is true. In fact, $Y(t)$ is nonempty for all $t < T$, where $T = \sup {|z - y|: y \in Y}$. This follows from the fact that $|z-y|$ is continuous in $y$ and the image of a connected set under a continuous function is connected.

If $Y$ has finitely many connected components, then $z$ is in the closure of one of the components. If that component is not a singleton, then just apply the previous result on connected $Y$ to get the desired result.

I accepted @K.Jiang answer. But I find your method interesting. I'm trying to figure it out. thank you!!!

Connectedness of $Y$ is sufficient for the condition you mention, although it is not necessary (as shown by the nice example in the comment from @WishYouTheBest).
Suppose $Y$ is connected, and let $z \in \text{Cl} Y$. Let $s > 0$ be such that there exists some $y_0 \in Y$ with $d (z, y_0) = s$, and let $t \in (0, s)$ be arbitrary. Suppose for the sake of contradiction that $\text{Bd} B_d (z, t)$ misses $Y$. The open sets $B_d (z, t)$ and $\text{Ext} B_d (z, t)$ would separate $Y$: they are disjoint, open, and their intersections with $Y$ are non-empty ($B_d (z, t)$ intersects $Y$ by virtue of the fact that $z \in \text{Cl} Y$, and $d (z, y_0) = s > t \implies y_0 \in \text{Ext} B_d (z, t) \cap Y$).
If $Y$ has a finite number of (connected) components, the situation is similar. Let $\{ C_1, \dots, C_N \}$ be the components of $Y$. Take $C_k$ in the collection such that $z \in \text{Cl} C_k$ (where the closure is taken treating $ C_k \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$). Such $k \in \{ 1, \dots, N \}$ must exist due to the fact that $\text{Cl} Y = \text{Cl} \left( \bigcup_{i = 1}^N C_i \right) = \bigcup_{i = 1}^N \text{Cl} C_i$. Then, apply the result in the previous paragraph, replacing $Y$ with $C_k$.

Your choice of $s > 0$ such that there exists $y_0 \in Y$ with $d(z, y_0) = s$ implicitly assumes $Y$ is not a singleton. If $Y$ is a singleton such an $s$ clearly does not exist. For the case of finitely many connected components, you also similarly have to avoid the case where $z$ is an isolated point of $Y$ itself.

@DavidGao Those cases are trivial, but yes, to be precise, $z$ should not be an isolated point of $Y$ (otherwise the collection $Y (t)$ will be empty for all $t$ sufficiently small).

Thank you all for your precious time!!!
